# How do I get this text residing within the tags using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch the number `121` from the above code. But the soup object that I am getting is not showing the number.

[Link to my Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqkXX.png)

```
    [<div class="open_pln" id="pln_1">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <div class="box_check_txt">
 <input id="cp1" name="cp1" onclick="change_plan(2,102,2);" type="checkbox"/>
 <label for="cp1"><span class="green"></span></label>
 </div>
 </li>
 <li id="li_open"><span>Desk</span> <br/></li>
 <li> </li>
 </ul>
 </div>]
```

Comment: Share your website link.

Comment: https://www.coworker.com/search/los-angeles/ca/united-states

I want to get the count of 'Desk'  and 'Private Office'  which are there in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The number `121` for open offices is not inside HTML code, but in the JavaScript. You can use `regex` to extract it:

```
import re
import requests

url ='https://www.coworker.com/search/los-angeles/ca/united-states'

htmlpage = requests.get(url).text

open_offices = re.findall(r'var openOffices\s*=\s*(\d+)', htmlpage)[0]
private_offices = re.findall(r'var privateOffices\s*=\s*(\d+)', htmlpage)[0]

print('Open offices: {}'.format(open_offices))
print('Private offices: {}'.format(private_offices))
```

Prints:

```
Open offices: 121
Private offices: 40
```

Comment: Thanks man. A couple of questions if I may ask there. How did you find it was inside the JavaScript and how did your get the code for them?

Comment: @PranavM I looked at the source code in Firefox and searched for string `121`. The only meaningful occurence of this string was inside some Javascript function so I extracted it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Without `re` module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.coworker.com/search/los-angeles/ca/united-states'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
searchstr = "var openOffices = "
script = soup.select_one(f"script:contains('{searchstr}')").text
print(script.split(searchstr)[1].split(";")[0])
```

Output:

```
121
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to find all the `li` attribute using soup like this -

```
    attribute=req["li"]       
    all_links = soup.find_all(attribute)
    for link in all_links:
        print(link.text.strip())
```